# Access token expires

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I have used the RingCentral Client v. 2.3.4.

I have implemented the OAuth authorization to get the access token which is then stored in the DB. We also have set auto refresh token property to true. We handled the refresh token event and updated the access token in the database. We use this token from DB to create detailedtelephony event till here every things works fine but after some time might be after couple of hours token get expired.

Is there any way so that we can keep this token valid without user intervention.

Answer (score 2):

Each RingCentral user could have at most 5 live access/refresh tokens. Let's say you use the same user credentials to request access/refresh tokens 6 times in a short time. Then the first access/refresh token you requested is invalidated.

Could it be your case?  Are you using the same RingCentral user credentials in multiple apps? Is so, it is very likely that you have more than 5 live tokens and the oldest one stored in your db is invalidated.

**Update:**

You can also disable the auto refresh feature: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client#auto-refresh And do refresh manually whenever the access token expires(before refresh token also expires). That way you don't need to listen to the refresh event because all the refresh actions are initiate by your code. Just remember to update DB after each refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know to use token efficiently and generate the access token in such a way that you don't need to call and generate them frequently but only in the case when required just before expiration.

Access token lifetime is 3600s = 1 hour 
Refresh token lifetime is 7 days(1 week)

You can renew access token and refresh token for every 1 hour. The expires_at  time provides allows you to know when you need to refresh a token and regularly checking it will allow you to refresh it as and when required. You don't need to call it too frequently before every API call.

You can refresh a token that is not expired and you can do it before it expires using refresh token. The previous access token will be immediately purged and a new access token will be returned. There will only ever be one active access token at a time for each instance.

If you can maintain access token and refresh token cycle for a long run of token.. in this way you can avoid expiration of token most of the case if the cycle not break even you save and retrieve it from database

more ref: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/articles/1426/generating-access-token-and-refresh-token-and-effi.html